# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled (thrown from Form constructor)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Okay, so here's a slightly detailed overview of what I'm dealing with:

- I'm creating a form with a standardized treeview to select a Patient.
- From that patient, the associated jobs are selected from comboboxes
  at the top of two Datagridviews.
- Once two jobs are selected, each datagridview populates with related
  authorizations which can then be dragged and dropped to the other
  job's datagridview in order to reassign it/them.

Slightly less detailed synopsis:

I'm trying to handle a sequence of drag and drop events between two datagridviews. So far, **they work most of the time**, but when the last row is removed from either gridview, and the form attempts to refresh, the Program.cs file throws an exception when trying to create a new Form object.

The code from the Program.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Job2JobTransfer
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); // this is where the error gets thrown.
        }
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough, right? It makes me wonder if there's something hidden in a constructor that I'm not considering, or if I'm just too dull to recognize my own mistake.

Here is the code I wrote for the drag drop events in order of dgv1_mousedown, dgv2_dragEnter, and dgv2_dragDrop. The reverse is the same code just renamed.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = e.RowIndex;
            dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.Rows[index], DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = e.RowIndex;
            dataGridView2.DoDragDrop(dataGridView2.Rows[index], DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView otherGridView = (DataGridView)sender;

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewRow)))
            {
                if (!dataGridView1.Rows.Contains((DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow))))
                {
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

 private void dataGridView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView otherGridView = (DataGridView)sender;

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewRow)))
            {
                if (!dataGridView2.Rows.Contains((DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow))))
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

private void dataGridView2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow tempRow = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
            WorkAuthorization tempAuth = new WorkAuthorization();
            tempAuth = (WorkAuthorization)tempRow.DataBoundItem;

            dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
            workAuthList2.Add(tempAuth);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = workAuthList2;

            try
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                workAuthList1.Remove(tempAuth);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = workAuthList1;
            }
            catch
            {
                int index = 0; //For the sake of a break point while debugging
            }

            dataGridView2.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

I don't normally post things on this site, so I apologize if I made an error in formatting or anything. If so, let me know, and I'll do my best to correct it. The same goes for if I need to clarify something or include more information.
Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions anyone might be able to provide.

**Error Message:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Row index provided is out of range.
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.GetRowState(Int32 rowIndex)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowHeaderMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at Job2JobTransfer.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Rhunt\Subversion\WindowsApps\ContractPatients\Job2JobTransfer\Job2JobTransfer\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: You need to run your program in Debug mode which you can view more details.
This is the tutorial how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: @UçanKartal I did run it in debug mode though. The StackTrace that I posted above was taken from the detailed view. Should I post more of what was contained therein?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `dataGridView2.Refresh();` and  `dataGridView1.Refresh();` to see if problem are gone?

Comment: I did try that; yes. The only thing that changed was that the dgvrowadd and remove didn't display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.Rows[index], DragDropEffects.Move); or the other one are being called, but the index is invalid or the rows are empty or something like that.
It might be that for some reason one of the eventhandlers are called during the Initialization of your form. You could remove the eventhandlers from the designer file and move it to the Form.OnLoad instead. If the problem still appears, you could set a loading variable and proof in the eventhandlers if the form has been loaded.

Edit: You could also simply check if dataGridView1 and dataGridView2 contain rows at the index:

```
int index = e.RowIndex;
if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count() > 0 && index <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count()) {
    dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.Rows[index], DragDropEffects.Move); 
}
```

Edit 2:
This Code works without problems for me:

```
public class WorkAuthorization
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<WorkAuthorization> workAuthList1;
    private List<WorkAuthorization> workAuthList2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        workAuthList1 = new List<WorkAuthorization>();
        workAuthList1.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization1", Description = "Description1" });
        workAuthList1.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization2", Description = "Description2" });
        workAuthList1.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization3", Description = "Description3" });

        workAuthList2 = new List<WorkAuthorization>();
        workAuthList2.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization4", Description = "Description4" });
        workAuthList2.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization5", Description = "Description5" });
        workAuthList2.Add(new WorkAuthorization { Name = "Authorization6", Description = "Description6" });
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadAuthorizations1();
    }

    private void LoadAuthorizations1()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = workAuthList1;
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadAuthorizations2();
    }

    private void LoadAuthorizations2()
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = workAuthList2;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;
        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.Rows[index], DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView otherGridView = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewRow)))
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.Rows.Contains((DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow))))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView otherGridView = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewRow)))
        {
            if (!dataGridView2.Rows.Contains((DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow))))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow tempRow = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
        WorkAuthorization tempAuth = new WorkAuthorization();
        tempAuth = (WorkAuthorization)tempRow.DataBoundItem;

        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        workAuthList2.Add(tempAuth);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = workAuthList2;

        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            workAuthList1.Remove(tempAuth);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = workAuthList1;
        }
        catch
        {
            int index = 0; //For the sake of a break point while debugging
        }

        dataGridView2.Refresh();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. This could make sense. I still wouldn't understand why the event handler is firing, but it would explain the error.

Comment: I don't exactly know why it is like that. But I was once in a similar situation, where I had a ListView with drag & drop and it also fired the eventhandlers during the constructor. I never really figured out why, but moving the EventHandler assignment to OnLoad solved my problem.

Comment: Well, I went ahead and did a parameter check on the rows and index values before executing DoDragDrop.

However, it seems that the value for Rows.Count isn't updating by whatever time it's being checked, and the program still crashes.

Comment: Ok I tried your example and in my case it works. I've created 2 comboboxes with predefined items (in the designer) and 2 Lists<WorkAuthorization> which are filled in the constructor. A WorkAuthorization is a class with a name and a description.

Comment: x_x Ok again. I've done everything how you described it and in my case it works without any problems. Once a combobox item is selected, the data get populated to a datagridview. Same happens with the 2nd combobox, but it targets the 2nd datagridview. I can drag a row from the 1st to the 2nd datagridview and everything works without any troubles. And I use your code.
So I guess your problem must be the loading of the data. Can you give more details on your data loading process? I used the default .NET controls. It might also be a problem with your custom control, if you use one.

Comment: I've added the code of my example into the Edit 2 section of my answer.

Comment: I'll have to go back and try this. To be honest, I ended up getting frustrated with it and just doing the move between gridviews on button click, but it would feel nicer to have this drag/drop finally work.